# FBSDKLoginKit not redirect my app after login and confirm page

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, oauth, swift3

I'm integrating Facebook SDK 4.15.1, using Swift 3.0.

I have followed all the steps mentioned here in link
[Getting started with iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started), I'm able to login to Facebook and make authorizations using the Safari browser but after that control is not returning to my app and a blank page is shown. But when I press done button the delegate method `didCompleteWith result:` gets called with error `OAuthException`. Also the `OpenURL` method is never get called in my application. I also verified my property list file and the app id thoroughly, no error in bundle identifiers or in app id.

The blank page is not shown in devices < iOS 9.0.

Any help is appreciated.

Below is my code for login and get access token in Swift 3.0,

```
AppDelegate.swift
    import UIKit
    import CoreData
    import FBSDKCoreKit
    import FBSDKLoginKit
    import FBSDKShareKit

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate  {

   var window: UIWindow? 
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {   
            FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)   
            return true
        }

    func application(application: UIApplication,
                     openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)    
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate  {
    public func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
     }

        let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.center = self.view.center
        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginView.delegate = self    
}
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if error == nil {
        print("Success")

        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id,interested_in,gender,birthday,email,age_range,name,picture.width(480).height(480)"])
        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("fetched user: \(result)")
            }
        })
    }else{
        print("Failure")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the issue by adding below transport security keys in property list.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```